# Bigger than X but smaller than Y

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, counting, gs-conditional-formatting

I've been racking my brain on Google Spreadsheets to make my conditional format rule be greater than or equal to 14 and less than or equal to 20. The current code is this

```
=AND(DAYS(TODAY(),DATEVALUE(F:F))>=14,D:D <> "Exiled Emperor",D:D <> "High Council", D:D <> "Dark Council",D:D <> "Darth", M:M <> "Honorary")
```

Comment: sharte a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=(DAYS(TODAY(), DATEVALUE(F:F))>=14)*
 (DAYS(TODAY(), DATEVALUE(F:F))<=21)*
 (NOT(REGEXMATCH(D:D, "Exiled Emperor|High Council|Dark Council|Darth")))*
 (M:M<>"Honorary")
```